# Why Python `audioread.NoBackendError`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I want to put every audios's label and feature to list `labels` and `batch_features`, then I happen `audioread.NoBackendError` when the `batch_size` > `10`.

I understand it is a `librosa`'s error.
but the weird thing is if I annotate(#) the code`labels.append(label)` then error won't happen. like this:

```
# labels.append(label)
```

Then This is my code :

```
n_classes = 21023
n_steps=432
batch_size = 50
def mfcc_batch_generator(batch_size=50):
    labels = []
    batch_features=[]
    files = os.listdir('/home/cheng/audioset/noVideo/')
    n=len(files)
    for i in range(0,n):
        print(files[i])
        wave,sr=librosa.load(path+files[i])
        mfcc=librosa.feature.mfcc(wave,sr)
        label = dense_to_one_hot(int(os.path.splitext(files[i])[0]),n_classes)
        labels.append(label)
        mfcc = np.pad(mfcc,((0,0),(0,n_steps-len(mfcc[0]))), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
        batch_features.append(np.array(mfcc).T)
        if i>= batch_size:
            yield np.array(batch_features), np.array(labels)
            batch_features = []  # Reset for next batch
            labels = []


def dense_to_one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes=21023):
    return np.eye(num_classes)[labels_dense]

batch=mfcc_batch_generator(batch_size)
x,y=next(batch)
```

and this my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 41, in <module>
    x,y=next(batch)
  File "test.py", line 25, in mfcc_batch_generator
    wave,sr=librosa.load(path+files[i])
  File "/home/cheng/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 112, in load
    with audioread.audio_open(os.path.realpath(path)) as input_file:
  File "/home/cheng/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/audioread/__init__.py", line 116, in audio_open
    raise NoBackendError()
audioread.NoBackendError
```

My sample audio are here：
https://github.com/bravo325806/librosa_sample

Comment: Please post a proper  MCVE and the full traceback.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I revise it, is this ok?

Comment: This is still not a proper MCVE. And FWIW, the problem has nothing to do with commenting out the `labels.append(label)` line nor with the batch size (a proper MCVE would have cleared this).  You have to identify which of your file(s) raise this error, then check librosa's doc (and eventually the bug tracker) to find out what's wrong with your system config for those files. FWIW, googling for "librosa backend" yields a couple questions and issues in the bugtracker...

Comment: thank you for your response ,I will improve my question in the next time

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you are still struggling with this.
In my case, I am using CentOS 7, and this Error is because my system did not install ffmpeg.

If you want to test ffmpeg is installed or not, try this in console:
$ ffmpeg

Just follow this [instruction](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-centos) and problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Windows, you have to install
[ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) firstly. Here you can find detailed [guide](https://windowsloop.com/install-ffmpeg-windows-10/), about installation.

After you're finished, reload your console and Jupyter Notebook. Everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to **ffmpeg**
In Anaconda try this `conda update ffmpeg`/`conda install ffmpeg` which worked for me in `Ubuntu 16.04`